# Convert alphanumeric (base-36) sentences into hexadecimal (base-16) sentences

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion, alphabet, cryptography, hexadecimal

I use "sentence" here loosely to mean "any sequence of words separated by spaces" and "words" to mean "sequences of alphanumeric (hexatrigesimal) characters unseparated by spaces".

---

Conversion is from base-36 (0123456789abcdefg...) or (0123456789ABCDEFG...)

Conversion to base-16 (0123456789abcdef) or (0123456789ABCDEF)

**Bonus -1** off your byte score if you are case-insensitive on input

**Bonus -1** off your byte score if you are insensitive to non-alphanumeric characters (ignore them, except space)

---

Conversion of sentences

E.g. if your input sentence is "The meaning of life is 31313" then your out put should convert the following base-36 "words" into base-16 numbers (the, meaning, of, life, is, 31313) and then output them in order.

**Bonus -1** off your byte score for retaining spaces in output sentence

### Test Cases

You may convert these to your preferred single-case form if you choose not to opt for the case-insensitive bonus, strings end after spaces. Assume input will never start with a space.

---

```
Input text:

"The meaning of life is 31313"

Output: ("9542 B59F1602C 36F F508A 2A4 4DA897") - with or without spaces, with lower or upper case letters
```

**Bonus -1** off your byte score for removing **leading zeroes** i.e. "9542" not "000009542".

---

```
Input text: 

"Jet fuel can't melt steel beams"

Output: ("6245 B47AD 8C0F9 FF371 2E28A2D 1241854")
```

---

```
Input text: 

"fhs8230982t90u20's9sfd902 %2'+13jos32*'ej eos"

Output: ("74510A686B453A2B1933C7AADA25DD2 BB8E18A11AEB 4A5C")
```

### The Winner

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the fewest bytes wins (including **bonus -1** bytes). :)

Can accept the inputs in any way that works, as long as your code can solve arbitrary problems like the test cases.

Comment: *bonus -1 bytes* only one byte? Also, bonuses in code-golf are generally discouraged

Comment: Yes, I had a feeling it might be like that, but I wanted to give a minor incentive. All four bonuses add up nicely for any language that implicitly does them, but still definitely not worth adding characters to solve them.

Comment: @DrQuarius The bonuses don't add anything interesting for the golfer -- either the language base-conversion has that feature and it's a free -1 byte, or it doesn't and it's not worth adding anything to their code to achieve it. The bonuses are just clutter in the challenge and in scoring.

Comment: @xnor hmm, thanks for the explanation. I will avoid them in future, but don't want to 'move the goalposts' now, so to speak.

Comment: By `removing leading zeros` do you mean ignoring them in input or not outputting them?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance in the output: so that 000009542 becomes 9542.

Comment: Very tempted to `-1` this for getting the mean of life so very wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 - 3 = 3 bytes

```
¸®n36G
```

Saved two bytes thanks to @Shaggy

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=uK5uMzZH&input=IlRoZSBtZWFuaW5nIG9mIGxpZmUgaXMgMzEzMTMi)

Comment: Very nice, and you **do** indeed remove leading zeros. so yeah 8-3=5 (but you said 8-2=5 in current edit). You also ignore apostrophes but get NaN for the %2'+13jos32*'ej string in the third test case, so -3 out of -4 bonus.

Comment: I think yours will probably be the winner. :) Your Japt golfing is marvellous!

Comment: `n36G` saves you 2 bytes.

Comment: @DrQuarius, that "bonus" would *cost* at least 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 28 bytes - 2 = 26

```perl6
{S:g{\S+}=:36(~$/).base(16)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxCsIwFEbh2TzFP0hJESqlkKHSF3Cto0sqNzWQpNIbhxLiq8dwpg/Oh3anij/QGEwoaR7X9JwveRoHJX/na9stmkn2qs3lJsy2QzobiFskcWJ9oGuMyOXxJnjSwYYVm4GzhmAZQ18Td4owX3J46RDr5iI4UvVC2vMf)

Comment: So fast! and very nice!

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL) array, 9 - 1 = 8 bytes

```
Yb36ZA1YA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxDsMgDEXRX3lbVmOkKoxZO3dJN9KahgjIYOf7CarudKVTo5Xe180/3otbl96n1y6oEltuP5wJJSdBVng3AhHhKYZ0ScEnNhu0GNRk/Cax6p@kXWf2FGa2QBeTBk3fQAx2/jjVsxyQU6cb)

Case-insensitive, but turns spaces into line breaks.

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL) inline, 20-2 = 18 bytes (inelligible)

```
Yb36ZA1YAO10Z(!999e!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxCoAgFEbhV/mdalSEwNG1paVFN41rCWqDt@c3OdMHpwYuY7ioN2@Vs4eSfhXGGBJjLOdDqBRabjfehJITIXdoNYOUEjsx0kcFV2g818LoTNORQu3LDw)

Takes case-insensitive and preserve-spaces bonuses, ([last test case fails due to implicit size assumptions = inelligible submission](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzLJ2CzK0TDS0d/QIEpD0dLSMlXx/3/1tIxiCyNjA0sLoxJLg1Ijg2LL4rQUSwMjBSND46z8YmOj1CyF1PxidQA))

```
Yb     % Split the input at spaces, place the results in a cell array
36ZA   % convert from base-36
1YA    % Convert to hexadecimal. Gives a char array 

O10Z(  % Assign char 0 to 10th column. Adds "Spaces"
!999e! % Reshape in row-major order as a 999-column char array
       % Implicitly display. Display 0 as space.
```

(I hope Luis Mendo comes and improves on this, because I got most of this from his answers [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103403/print-the-f-%C3%97-f-times-table/103406#103406), [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66426/numbers-that-are-actually-letters/66431#66431), [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102781/output-the-html-colors/102803#102803) and sundar's answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/168640/search-text-for-a-prefix-and-list-all-its-suffixes-in-the-text).)

Comment: Good job. I came but I don't see how to improve it :-D

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, 23-1 = 22 bytes

Only uses the case-insensitive bonus.

```ruby
$_=$_.to_i(36).to_s(16)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYqxCsIwFEX39xUP7GARtU1AzODq4Oxe2npjU2IivlfEn7dW7nLO4b6m7jPPRXMqmp3mJqztofyDrOtDuXTenLjY84rP@cU6gBPeMSRwB30DiRWi3LcC4ZziZ74OoAfaFNKdsqcYPCgI2XoZXaDkJ0Tq26TLLSqJYvEO7UPID3I0tnJHo66aTCVO/M1VhkxtxyzWYCRk@eanhpxk3j5/)

### Ruby `-p`, 33-2 = 31 bytes

Takes case-insensitive and preserve-spaces bonuses.

```ruby
gsub(/\w+/){$&.to_i(36).to_s(16)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsIwEADvfcUeRFqkNk2gNF/w7FGQRDdtSpsUd4OI@HVjZS4zMI9kXzkPlGzZXJ6Hpnrv9keOV1@qrvoLlW1XfXI@jwgLmuDDANHB7B2CJ1DtRnFCBpdwhpsJvG0zAzFubdEsVLiReqmE7iVrkaQgTe6uhQTZqimSkjgBRvrGlX0MlOv1Bw)

## Ruby `-p`, 46-3 = 43 bytes

Takes all 3 bonuses.

```ruby
gsub(/\S+/){$&.gsub(/\W/){}.to_i(36).to_s(16)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYrBDoIwEAXvfMUe1IJEKG1C4Be8auLFxIBuoQRa4paDMfy6tSZmLm9e5rm0L@87Wto4v57SPHlvdtlfL8HWzNmbjmWZ/AbFRZms3p97hAkbo00HVsGoFYImkEUgOqIDteAI98YwF7rRATkMR4vNRJHqqRKS15VwNV8EZ1STetRcwFawtJCDJSn2DAdASx87O20N@cP8BQ)

Comment: No need for parentheses around the last method's argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 20 characters

```
<A>=@radix{36;16;$1}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema '<A>=@radix{36;16;$1}' <<< 'The meaning of life is 31313'
9542 B59F1602C 36F F508A 2A4 4DA897
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/38bRztahKDEls6La2Mza0MxaxbD2//@QjFSF3NTEvMy8dIX8NIWczLRUhcxiBWNDIOTySi1RSCtNzVFITswrASrLKVEoLkkF8pNSE3OLAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score 3 (4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) - 1 bonus)

```
#₆öh
```

Bonus -1: no leading 0s, since this is done implicitly.
Outputs as a list of converted words.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f@VFT2@FtGf//h2SkKuSmJuZl5qUr5Kcp5GSmpSpkFisYGwKhgldqiUJaaWqOQnJiXglQWU6JQnFJKpCflJqYWwwA)

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score 8 (12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) - 4 bonus)

```
u#εžKÃ}₆öhðý
```

All four bonuses:
-1 for no leading 0s, since this is done implicitly;
-1 case-insensitivity by first converting to uppercase with `u`;
-1 for retaining spaces in the output by joining the list by spaces with `ðý`;
-1 for ignoring every character apart from `[A-Za-z0-9 ]`, by keeping `[A-Za-z0-9]` after the split_on_spaces with `εžKÃ}`

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##DcoxDgIhEEDRq0xiDIk27NAsV9DWC7A6CBt2KQbKbTTxPDbaaUNsPYQXQfK7lx/ZDJ5qzavv4/Pel@vyu9zK05V7edV6cAQTmdnPZ4gWgrcEnkF1LdhRApspwNHMIrUvJOBEDQYyE4N13KOSusekZUYpWLM9aYmwRrHt1BhZ4UbQCBT5Dw)

**Explanation:**

```python
#             # Split the (implicit) input-string on spaces
 ₆ö           # Convert each string from base-36 to integers
   h          # Convert those integers to hexadecimal
              # (and output the list implicitly as result)

u             # Convert the (implicit) input to uppercase
 #            # Split it on spaces
  ε           # Map each string to:
   žK         #  Push builtin string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
     Ã        #  And only keep those characters in the mapped string
      }₆ö     # After the map: convert each string from base-36 to integer
         h    # Convert those integer to hexadecimal
          ðý  # And join them by spaces
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 - 2 = 45 bytes

```python
lambda S:[hex(int(s,36))[2:]for s in S.split()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHYKjojtUIjM69Eo1jH2ExTM9rIKjYtv0ihWCEzTyFYr7ggJ7NEQzP2f0ERUI1CmoZ6SUaqQmpeioKBkaGRobrmfwA)

Because case insensitive. And also leading `0`s.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mbigint -MList::Util=reduce -p`, 92 - 4 = 88 bytes

```perl
y/_/*/;s|\S+|Math::BigInt::as_hex reduce{$a*36+$b}map{7x/\d/+ord(uc)-55}$&=~/\w/g|ge;s/0x//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc5BC4IwGIDhv@LBshT71sRKpUu3IE/RTRDNNRfmxG@SkfbTW0Kn9z0@DWsrX@sXpGBDhENydoY4U2UYHgQ/1ioMM0xL1hstK7ore5uZ7W0cMx8fWfPe9pAU4Mi2WHTXpev7oznffyB5Ah84ixBID8C1vpUp7qhHgh1VAekosTDAWxEQasyo5ay9u0SP2ha7G0ziVzZKyBq1G/srsiZTc8FFraY5CZxIFyWq/R@k3eYH)

Qualifies for all 4 bonuses (case insensitive, keeps spaces, ignores punctuation, no leading 0s).  Handles even large test cases properly, including the last one.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes - 1, score 13

```
⪫Ｅ⪪Ｓ ⍘⍘ι³⁶¦¹⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMrPzNPwzexQCO4ICezRMMzr6C0JLgEKJWuoamjoKSgBCSdEotToWJIzEwdBWMzoKyhmSZUpab1//8lGakKuamJeUAVCvlpCjmZaakKmcUKxoZAyPVftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Only qualifies for the leading zeros bonus. Explanation:

```
   Ｓ            Input string
  ⪪             Split on spaces
 Ｅ              Map over words
       ι        Current word
      ⍘ ³⁶      Convert from base 36
     ⍘     ¹⁶   Convert to base 16
⪫               Join on spaces
                Implicitly print
```

- If output of the hex numbers on separate lines is acceptable, then the first and last characters can be removed for a 2-byte saving.
- Case insensitive input is possible at a cost of 1 byte, which would not affect the score.
- Preservation of multiple spaces is possible at a cost of 2 bytes, unless the current misbehaviour is a Charcoal bug, in which case it would work once the bug is fixed.
- Skipping of punctuation is possible at a cost of 4 bytes. (Currently the only supported case is a single trailing `.`)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 94-2 = 92 bytes

These "bonuses" are too expensive to intentionally claim. I get case insensitive and leading zeros for free though.

```java
s->{for(var w:s.split(" "))System.out.print(new java.math.BigInteger(w,36).toString(16)+" ");}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##LY67CsIwFIb3PMWhU4IaEMHBooOD4Fw3cThoUk9tk5IcW6T02Wu88I/ff6uww0V1e0zk2ASLVwOHQXSebmBlwYFcCVHlIjIyXeELGiT3Z@cLqkEcwMJ2iovdYH2QHQboN1HHtiaWGWRKFa/IptH@ybpNMZbO9FClad0g3/WeymOaL02Q/Xy1Vpr9r14u12r2acjHKRdWW5md7gYag@5zzFuoyRqgCKtlUvKJcZze)

Answer (score 0):

## Ecmascript 2020, score 90 - 3 = 87

Likely it would be there, already works in Firefox 68+ and Chrome 67+.

```
s=>s.replace(/\w+/g,x=>[...x].reduce((r,x)=>36n*r+BigInt(parseInt(x,36)),0n).toString(16))
```

Bonuses:

- Bonus -1 off your byte score if you are case-insensitive on input
- Bonus -1 off your byte score for retaining spaces in output sentence
- Bonus -1 off your byte score for removing leading zeroes i.e. "9542" not "000009542".

Test:

```js
f=s=>s.replace(/\w+/g,x=>[...x].reduce((r,x)=>36n*r+BigInt(parseInt(x,36)),0n).toString(16))

console.log([
["The meaning of life is 31313", "9542 B59F1602C 36F F508A 2A4 4DA897"],
["Jet fuel can't melt steel beams", "6245 B47AD 8C0F9 FF371 2E28A2D 1241854"],
["fhs8230982t90u20's9sfd902 %2'+13jos32*'ej eos", "74510A686B453A2B1933C7AADA25DD2 BB8E18A11AEB 4A5C"],
["  123   1234   tyu ", "  55B   C0D0   97B6 "],
].map(([t,k])=>f(t.replace(/(?!\s|_)\W/g,"")).toUpperCase()==k))
```